# Space between two image using css

Tags: html, css

`css` is bothering me with the positioning. I have a lot of pictures to implement and I have centered all classes this is working fine. But I need individual space between the pictures. Percent or pixel doesn`t matter.

This is the Code in the `Html` File:

```
<div class="picture">
  <!—PIC1 -->
  <a href="http://.....” target="_blank">
    <img src="pic2"  width="149" height="114">
  </a>
  <!—PIC2 -->
  <a href="http://.....” target="_blank">
    <img src="pic1"  width="149" height="114">
  </a>
  </a>
</div>
```

A part of the `CSS` is looking like this:

```
.pictures {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    /* please help*/
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: Please fix the typos in your code.

Comment: have you tried using `padding` or `margin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Hearty/va8o2meL/) on JSFiddle.

```
a{
   text-decoration:none;
}
img{
   margin:1em;
   /* Space will be occupied all four sides Top, Right, Bottom & Left */
}
```

Comment: so simple and so easy. thx and alle the best and if i oversize it will go to the next line right ? cheers

Comment: Yup it depends on your screen size, if it is not fitting then certainly will go to next line.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify anything you can try this:

```
img{
  margin-right:10px; //your space here
}
```